# VS Code - Imports are not resolved in python virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have created a virtual environment for TensorFlow but all my imports are not working properly. They are showing me a yellow line.

[image: screenshot of my code imports]

Tried this solution as well
Also, I tried many solutions but nothing is working

Error is: [image]

Comment: if you don't activate/select the virt env nothing will change

Comment: I have already selected the virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

##### You need to choose the correct python interpreter.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`

  [image]

If you use the `pip` command in the terminal to install those packages, but you can't be sure that they are actually installed in the virtual environment. So switch interpreters, choose the python environment that installed them

Or select a virtual environment interpreter and create a new terminal, the terminal will automatically activate the virtual environment. At this point, install those packages under the terminal that activates the virtual environment.

[image]

You can also check where the package is installed using the `pip show packagename` command.